# pandas fill value between the index of two rows(rows only find by a value)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, fill

I have a Series `df`:

```
index 
0     1
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1
5    -1
6    -1
7    -1
8     1
9     1
10    1
11   -1
dtype: int64
```

Another `boolean` Series is likes indicator or points `b`:

```
index 
0     False
1     False
2     True
3     False
4     False
5     False
6     True
7     False
8     False
9     True
10    False
11    False
```

I can set the `df` values using `b`, `df[b]=0`:

```
index 
0     1
1     1
2     0
3     1
4     1
5    -1
6     0
7    -1
8     1
9     0
10    1
11   -1
```

And now what I want to fill the values between `2:5`,`6:7`,`9:11` with the value `-1` and the result I want is a new `df`:

```
index 
0     1
1     1
2    -1
3    -1
4    -1
5    -1
6    -1
7    -1
8     1
9    -1
10   -1
11   -1
```

Which means when `b` is `True`, (index:2,6,9), I would fill the value `1` in `df` between the index(index:2,6,9) and the index of the nearest `-1` values (index:5,7,11).

The fill value is `-1`, the fill range is `[2:5,6:7,9:11]`

I've thought method like `where`, `replace`, `pad` etc, but cannot work it out. Maybe find its index array `[2,6,9]`,and the nearest `-1` array `[5,7,11]`, and rearrange into `[2:5,6:7,9:11]` is a way.

Is there some ways more useful?

Comment: Why isn't the nearest value to 9 7? Are you only looking down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numpy.where()` looks like it can do what you need:

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np

starts = np.where(df == 0)
ends = np.where(df == -1)
for start, end in zip(starts[0], ends[0]):
    df[start:end] = -1
```

**Test Data:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1])
b = pd.DataFrame([False, False, True, False, False, False, True,
                  False, False, True, False, False,])
df[b] = 0
print(df)
```

**Results:**

```
    0
0   1
1   1
2  -1
3  -1
4  -1
5  -1
6  -1
7  -1
8   1
9  -1
10 -1
11 -1
```

Comment: OP: Is it always the case that `starts` and `ends` will have the same length? If so, this looks good to me.

Comment: thanks very much! that's what I wanna.And a little code changed into:`for start in starts[0]:
  df[start:ends[0][ends[0]>start][0]]=-1` as to find the nearest end.@Geoff it   is not always the case.It'll calucate end each time.